# PerformanceCounter not working when run as a service

Tags: c#, silverlight, performancecounter

```
Unhandled error: Counter '% Processor Time' does not exist in the specified Category. - Counter '% Processor Time' does not exist in the specified Category. System.InvalidOperationException System.Diagnostics.CounterDefinitionSample GetCounterDefinitionSample(System.String)    at System.Diagnostics.CategorySample.GetCounterDefinitionSample(String counter)
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.NextSample()
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.NextValue()
```

is the error message that shows up for one of our customers for the below code when run within our Silverlight web application started from a Windows Service. He runs it on a Windows Server 2016. This is the second time we have seen this exact error over a period of 20 years. So it doesn't happen often.

```
PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
double cpu = cpuCounter.NextValue();
```

I put these two lines into a test .Net console application and asked the customer to run it on the server, and it works just fine. The test application also got all of the available categories, and "Process" was one of them. I saw that a lot of the counters are localized. I also had the customer to run

```
lodctr /R
```

in case there was a mess up in the Performance Counter library. This did not help. He had to run this command in the syswow64 folder as it failed otherwise.

When the customer ran the test application he was logged into windows as an administrator. The Windows Service is running as Local System account.

Any ideas why it might fail?

Edit:
Setting the local administrator on the Log on tab for the service did not help